# Is this the right way to write getter and setter method in apex?

Tags: apex

I am newbie and I am writing my getter and setter method as follwing

```
@Testvisible
    private static Set<String> customerTypes{
        get{
            if(customerTypes == null){
                for(Customer__mdt meta : [SELECT Id,CustomerType__c FROM Customer__mdt]){
                    customerTypes.add(meta.CustomerType__c);
                }
            }
            return customerTypes;
        }
        private set;
    }
```

I get the error while using this set of values in my other method

```
Set<String> customerTypesValid = customerTypes;
```

Error : Attempt to dereference a null object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is on me, I should have provided more guidance in my original answer).

In your getter method, as you're querying your Custom Metadata Type to populate the property value, you do have to create the collection instance first. Apex isn't smart enough to auto-initialize it for you.

So in your getter, you'd do this:

```
    get{
        if(customerTypes == null){
            customerTypes = new Set<String>(); // Note that we initialize the collection here.
            for(Customer__mdt meta : [SELECT Id,CustomerType__c FROM Customer__mdt]){
                customerTypes.add(meta.CustomerType__c);
            }
        }
        return customerTypes;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, now I get my test metadata values in set method too.. CHEERS!!!! :D

Comment: @user3920709 Awesome, I'm glad that worked out. Keep this pattern in your back pocket - it's really useful for a wide variety of use cases, both testing and non-testing.

Comment: To be fair, *most* languages won't auto-initialize your variables. One should always remember to initialize a variable before using it.

Comment: @DavidReed can you provide some examples of usage for getters and setters in SF ?

Comment: @Json - I use the aforementioned pattern all the time in VF controllers as it solves many issues: idempotency and an easy way to reset and refetch (by setting properties to null) when underlying source data has changed through some action within the VF controller.  Rather than constructors initializing properties, I let them init themselves on demand